# R exists function?

Tags: function, r, loops, statistics

Hello I want to compare file from two directories:

```
allfilenames <- list.files(path="../XYZ")  
names1=allfilenames[grep("XYZ_*",allfilenames)]
numfiles <- length(names1) 

allfilenames2 <- list.files(path="../ABC")  
names2=allfilenames2[grep("ABC_*",allfilenames2)]
numfiles <- length(names2) 

for(i in names1){
if(exists(i in names2){...}###?????
else...
}
```

Is exists function is not right! Is there another function to lookwhether a file from one director exists in the other?

Comment: In an index, you are better using `grepl` rather than` grep`.  When there are no matches, `grep` returns an empty numeric vector, which causes the index to return everything (instead of nothing).

Answer (score 5):

To test whether one character string is inside another, use `%in%`, for example:

```
names <- c("A", "B", "D")

"A" %in% names
[1] TRUE

"C" %in% names
[1] FALSE
```

`exists` tests whether an object exists or not. In your case you simply want to test whether a statement is true or false.

Answer (score 5):

Not `exists`, but `file.exists`.

---

In response to Karsten.

OP's question:

> Is there another function to look[ ]whether a file from one director[y]
>   exists in the other?

An extended version of my answer

```
file.exists(file.path(some_other_dir, a_file_from_one_directory))
```

This adequately answers the question.

Comment: `file.exists` is not helpful for OP's question.

Comment: @Karsten: Sigh. Yes it is, you simply lack imagination.

Comment: thanks for helping my imagination, I changed my voting accordingly. maybe I should sleep more

Answer (score 2):

Rather than testing the elements in one of those file.name vectors one by one, why not use `intersect`?

```
intersect(names1, names2)
```

You can test for no common names with `length( intersect(a,b) ) == 0`

Answer (score 2):

Jasmine, first you can give a pattern to list.files directly instead of using grep - but in any case the pattern needs to be a regular expression. Then you can use set operations to do intersection, union or difference on your file names:

```
# "^XYZ_" matches strings that START with "XYZ_"
names1 <- list.files("../XYZ", pattern="^XYZ_")
names2 <- list.files("../ABC", pattern="^ABC_")

# The names in both folders
commonNames <- intersect(names1, names2)

# The names only in the first folder
uniqueNames1 <- setdiff(names1, names2)

# The names only in the second folder
uniqueNames2 <- setdiff(names2, names1)

# Loop and process...    
for(i in commonNames) {
  #...
}
```

If you still wan to use grep, you can use value=TRUE to get the values out. Again, the pattern was incorrect, so it should be something like:

```
names2 <- grep("^ABC_", allfilenames2, value=TRUE)
```